# Intel AX200 Wi-Fi adapter not working

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, in settings it says Wi-Fi adapter not found. However, bluetooth still works. My Wi-Fi card is an Intel AX200. I have installed the firmware from Intel's website (by copying it into /lib/firmware). According to the instructions, after copying the file I should load the driver which I did by doing `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. Also I am running kernal `5.6.0` which is above the minimum kernal on the Intel website, and Wi-Fi works in Windows 10 (which I have in dual boot right now).
After runnning `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` I get the following:

```
[    4.126373] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.206832] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:0f:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? If there is anything else I need to run please tell me. Thanks!

**Update:**
This is what I get when running `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**More UPDATE!**:
Okay, so after turning off fast boot (in Windows) the Wi-Fi adapter is found. However, every time I connect it says `Connection Failed`

**Last UPDATE!**:
Installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with 3rd party software enabled and it works now!

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @kazamatzuri I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and enabled install proprietary drivers, and it worked.

Comment: Please don't put the solution inside the question. You can answer your own question by pressing the button below.

Answer (score 0):

On dual boot installation (Ubuntu + Windows 10), disabling "Turn on fast startup" in Windows resolved the problem for me. It's well hidden in Windows:

- In *Power Options* Windows settings
- Select *Choose what the power buttons do* menu option on left
- Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable* link
- Uncheck *Turn on fast startup (recommended)* option