# Asus TUF GAMING B550 PLUS WIFI, INTEL AX200 WIFI not working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: wireless, intel, 20.10

I'm currently stuck trying to get the WIFI working (the Ethernet for this motherboard is also not working, if you have this, update your kernel to 5.10, for example using Mainline).

sudo dmesg | grep iwl gives:

```
[    3.612578] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    3.612582] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.612584] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.612755] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.13675109.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.684666] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```

According to the internet, the next lines should say:

```
iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

But my kernel is stopping here. It tries to load the firmware, but appears to be stopping after that and not making wlan0 visible as a network interface.

Searched the internet and couldn't find another way to fix this. The firmware: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html was already in /lib/firmware, and it looks like it tries to load the firmware.

Tried on kernel 5.11.0-rc7, 5.10.14 and the default 5.8.0.43.49

Answer (score 1):

Got it working,

Step 1: Disable all firmware (else it uses the wrong firmware)

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/backup/
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi* /lib/firmware/backup/
```

Step 2: Grep your firmware from: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html

Please use the iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz if you are on an AX200

Step 3: Unpack and move it to /lib/firmware:

```
sudo mv ~/iwlwifi* /lib/firmware/
sudo chown root:root /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*
```

Step 4, reboot and your output of sudo dmesg | grep iwlw should be:

```
[    3.672084] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.675743] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.675774] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.675858] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.675991] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676009] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676032] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676058] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676075] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676174] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676190] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676204] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676219] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.676234] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.678938] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.3cfab8da.0 cc-a0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.740970] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.903256] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: base HW address: b8:9a:2a:de:1d:e5
[    3.918135] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Skipping all the firmware until it loads the right firmware :)

Hope it helps someone.

Please note, windows could mess up this card: [Intel AX200 Wi-Fi adapter not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226036/intel-ax200-wi-fi-adapter-not-working)

Check this link if you are dualbooting :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Access BIOS and disable fast startup or fast boot. It worked for me in the AMD motherboard BIOS.
2. Restart your computer.